# MarkLogic privilege setting

Tags: marklogic

How do I set the privilege for set-session-field() function in MarkLogic for the application user? I cannot seem to find this information in the MarkLogic documentation and I currently get the following error when I try to use this function:

SEC-PRIV: xdmp:set-session-field("*myfield*", "*myvalue*") -- Need privilege: http://marklogic.com/xdmp/privileges/xdmp-set-session-field
in /my_xquery_file.xqy, at 48:6 [1.0-ml]

thx

p.s. Got this one:
OK, for anyone else who needs this information, I found it in the MarkLogic doc "Understanding and Using Security Guide" on page 28. Open the MarkLogic admin panel in your browser; Go to Configure->Security->Execute Privileges; Scroll down to find the function/privilege you want to grant and click on the specific function/privilege. In the next screen, check the app-user if you want your xquery scripts to execute the function.
My app can now store data in user sessions (set-session-field privilege).

Comment: Asked and answered in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer you give yourself is correct.

A link to the PDF copy of that manual can be found here: http://community.marklogic.com/docs (direct link: http://community.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/books/security.pdf ). The searchable docs site is also note worthy. It can be found here: http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy (direct link to the Execute Privileges section: http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/xml/security/execute.xml ).

Note though that MarkLogic's Security model is role-based. You assign the Execute Privilege to a role, and the user you authenticate with needs to have this role. So if your user has the app-user role, than the above is correct.

HTH!

Comment: So I guess I need to make sure that everyone who logs into my application has the app-user role now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than giving all users with the `app-user` role the ability to create session fields, you might also consider creating a library function that creates specific types of session fields (perhaps for specific users) and *amp* that function to a role that can create session fields. Amps allow you to elevate permissions temporarily for a specific function call. They allow a user to do privileged things in the context of an application without having to give that user blanket privilege to do that same task in any context. You can read more about amps in section 5.2 of the [Understanding and Using Security Guide](http://%20http://community.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/books/security.pdf) referenced above.